# make an install disk based on your current installed OS?

Tags: system-installation

So when I originally downloaded the Ubuntu 13.04 iso and installed it I added many different apps to it, now I want to create an install disk with all my apps that originally did not come with it, Gimp, Inkscape, Blender, ext, and the libs I have installed as well, xdotool for example, so I can install this on my laptop without having to manually install everything.

effectively create my own distro in a sense for my computers.

Comment: you may also like, [Relinux](http://mijyn.github.io/relinux/)

Answer (score 1):

Remastersys can do that. It's no longer supported, but the old version does work on Ubuntu 13.04 in my experience. Just visit [remastersys.org](http://remastersys.org) to get the repo information then sudo-apt get install remastersys, and sudo apt-get install remastersys-gui. You must launch it as root or it won't open. It will generate an iso file that you can burn to a dvd and use just like a normal installation disc.

Answer (score 0):

Try SystemImager.

SystemImager makes it easy to do automated installs (clones), software distribution, content or data distribution, configuration changes, and operating system updates to your network of Linux machines. You can even update from one Linux release version to another.<sup>[SystemImager](http://www.systemimager.org/)</sup>

To download, and more information visit [SystemImager](http://www.systemimager.org/).